# Uwp phone toolbar

Tags: win-universal-app, toolbar

I'd like to have a toolbar in my uwp app (only on phone version) and I can't figure it out. I'd like to make it like `Groove Music` store app have it on mobile phone :
[image]

I' d like to customize this toolbar with a toggle button and a title at least. So is there a way to do that on universal win?

Answer (score 1):

It will probably be slightly different than you are thinking. UWP doesn't think so much about "what device am I on" as it thinks about what screen size it is being displayed at. So when you design your app, you want the toolbar to appear only at screen sizes below a certain amount. The closest thing to what you want might be a Command Bar, which you can put at the bottom or top.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465302.aspx

Or you could make a custom XAML control that appears where you want it to and only shows up with a screen below a certain size. I hope this helps answer the question.

Comment: second solution sounds better for me, but how to include one xaml into the other one? I know in android is using    `<include layout="@layout/my_second_layout" />`

Comment: A Stackpanel, using multiple UI elements, should work - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.stackpanel.aspx